# error uploading file to server undefined index when uploading a photo to server

Tags: php

I have this php code and it cannot accept file uploads to the server, they tell me that undefined index file, how can i fix this error,

```
$target_path = public_path().'/uploads';
// dd($target_path);

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Upload and move success";
} else {
echo $target_path;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `var_dump($_FILES)` to your question?

Comment: Add forward slash at the end of `public_path().'/uploads/';`

Comment: Here $_FILES['file']['name'] -> 'file'-> should be name of the form field, Please check whether you using the name as 'file' or please put the code of your html also.

Answer (score 0):

One or more these keys in your $_FILES array is undefined/not being passed from your form:

```
['file']
['file']['name']
['file']['tmp_name']
```

You should print out the value of $_FILES to determine which is undefined:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Then trace back the missing key(s) to your input form. Maybe theres a typo in the form.

Comment: am going to check that out and reply asap